# cx_freeze doesn't accept os.chdir using variable

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have a created a python script that works well in Python 3.4 but when I package it with cx-freeze I get an error:

[image]

The code giving problems is:

```
desk = os.getenv("HOME") + '\Desktop'
os.chdir(desk)
```

I tried also:

```
desk = os.getenv("HOME")
desk = re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', desk)
desk = desk +'\\Desktop'
os.chdir(desk)
```

but got the same error.

If I use `os.chdir("c:\\users\\username\\Desktop)` everything works fine.

How do I make this script work even after cx-freeze?

Comment: AFAIK the `HOME` environment variable isn't usually set on Windows - you have to use `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` together.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
desk = home+'\Desktop'
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: it does solve the problem JUST FOR THAT CASE. what if I want to get current directory where the exe file running? while I can't use os.chdir